# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. : ...SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, hdp, spark2

I'm trying to do "101 - Intro to Spark" lab in Python via Zeppelin using Hortonworks Sandbox HDP 2.6.5, and when I get to counting words with a DataFrame, an error occurs.

When I try to execute this code:

```
%spark2.pyspark

# First, let's transform our RDD to a DataFrame.
# We will use a Row to define column names.
wordsCounts = (filteredWordCounts.map(lambda (w, c): 
                Row(word=w,
                    count=c))
                .toDF())

# Print schema
wordsCounts.printSchema()

# Output: As you can see, the count and word types have been inferred without having to explicitly define long and string types respectively.
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1872697133842828769.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1872697133842828769.py", line 355, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 58, in toDF
    return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 693, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 390, in _createFromRDD
    struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio, names=schema)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 361, in _inferSchema
    first = rdd.first()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1376, in first
    rs = self.take(1)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1358, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/context.py", line 1010, in runJob
    port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 25.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 25.0 (TID 49, sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 229, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 224, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1354, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'Row' is not defined
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 229, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 224, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1354, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'Row' is not defined
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

There is also "NameError: global name 'Row' is not defined", it seems like it doesn't see pyspark.sql.Row class.

Comment: you should import it?

Comment: `from pyspark.sql import Row` . I suggest this website for newbies learning spark. 

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-row-using-rdd-dataframe-2/ Use this as a reference.

Comment: Yes, import was the problem. Thank you all!